# Web Accessibility after WCAG 2.1 - Title on non-interactive element

Tags: html, accessibility, wcag

For my study project I'm currently checking an example website for WCAG 2.1 compliance.
Checking it with different tools I still get some Warnings I don't understand or know how to solve.
One of the warnings is "title on non interactive element": I have some title="" attributes on <div>, ,  and  elements and get a Success Criterion 3.3.2 Labels or Instructions warning.
I know the title attribute is not always read by the screen reader. But if I don't expect it to, where's the problem? I even tried to add an aria-label="" with the same content as the title but still get a warning for the title attribute.

```html
<div class="criterion_secion" id="criterion_214" title="Success Criterion '2.1.4 Character Key Shortcuts'" aria-label="Success Criterion '2.1.4 Character Key Shortcuts'">...</div>
```

Comment: It would be great to know what’s inside that element and why you are adding a title on it. If the title is adding information, that information needs to be accessible. And please mind that `aria-label` is actually *replacing* the element’s contents for assistive technology, at least for interactive elements.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the warning is given because it’s not expected to have a `label` or a `title` on a non-interactive element, like a `div`.

A `div` is by nature a non-interactive element. We could make it interactive through the `tabindex` attribute or by giving it a `role`. However, I would advice not to do that and just use the `div` for what it's intended, as a container.

Answer (score 0):

It make sense your tool are flagging title on non interactive element as a warning, because a lot of users can't access to your content in the title attribute. A warning doesn't mean it's automatically a failure.

The aria-label attribute on a div (without role attribute) is useless. This element have no semantic and it's not supposed to have an accessible name.

Answer (score 0):

## ARIA & Tooltips: 2 commonly misunderstood attributes

There is a very easy solution to this issue: remove both title and aria-label attributes and include their content that reads "Success Criterion '2.1.4 Character Key Shortcuts'" inside the DIV element, if not already included.

### aria-label

[The aria-label attribute defines a string value that **labels an interactive element**.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-label)
First of all, ARIA is for the screen readers only and it overwrites the accessible name of the element.
For example,

```
<label for="name" aria-label="surname">Name</label>
<input id="name" type="text" />
```

will be announced as "surname" and the screen reader user will never understand it is for the input field that collects users' "name".

As for the non-interactive elements, a paragraph never needs any aria-label for the simple reason that you can always include whatever information you want inside it. Besides, [it may not be read or may confuse your users as a non-interactive element that acts like an interactive one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-label#associated_roles).

It is also important to know that repeating what is already available as text with an aria-label is simply a nuisance, making the screen reader say the same thing twice or even thrice sometimes, along with a tooltip.

### Tooltips

Tooltips are intended for sighted users. They provide some extra information that was not made available elsewhere. [Examples from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title).

It is helpful to understand these:

- Tooltips are not accessibility features
- Repeating what is already available as text using the title attribute helps no one and annoys screen reader users. It is simply bad practice.

Here is a comprehensive resource that will probably make you think twice before using another tooltip: [If you want to hide content from mobile and tablet users as well as assistive tech users and keyboard only users, use the title attribute](https://www.tpgi.com/using-the-html-title-attribute-updated/).